# Delete everything in a reposity to recommit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a repository that has a lot of issues with it. A bunch of files were moved/names changed/ ect. Committing these throws an error.

What I want to do is fully delete everything in the repository so that I can recommit the project with the correct files/names/locations ect.

To do this I tried

1. updating the project then committing changes
2. Deleting the entire project (through tortoise) committing, adding files (again through tortise) and recommitting
3. Deleting every conflict file, re-adding it, clicking resolved, committing

None of these options worked for me (I get `Resource out of date, try updating`)

Is there a way I can just delete the entire project and recommit? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If I were in your shoes, I would probably just archive off that repository and create a new one.

Comment: @ssride, Your local files are good? Then you could just delete every local .svn folder and commit it all somewhere else.

Comment: Yea I think it would be easier at this point just to commit it somewhere else. This is taking way to much time/patience to figure out

Comment: Regardless of the amount of changes you have carried out, I cannot see a reason why committing those changes back to the original repo they produce any errors. Plus creating a new report will simply make historical changes in the original repo useless. What kind of errors are you getting while attempting the commit? This is the whole purpose of this tool, and if it were not possible to do it, many of use would be in real trouble.

Comment: @edalorzo. I get a resource out of date error. Deleting that file or updating it does not remove the error. I just looked into the repository on the other server, and just about every file there is out of date/deleted/in the wrong location. I think that through all these recommit/deletes/ect. I cause there to be errors in my svn files, or at least that the only reason that makes sense to me

Comment: @SsRide360 I have submitted an answer with alternative path of action. I really hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this idea:

1. Make a patch file of all your changes (in Eclipse this is utterly easy).
2. Then get a fresh version of your repo in another sandbox folder.
3. Then apply your patch file changes there.
4. Then try to commit your changes in the updated version of your repo.

That ought to work.

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I had to do. Thanks